# Locating the largest three-digit product - which is also a plaindrome

Tags: python, integer

```
def reverseInteger(x):
    x_string = str(x)                           
    x_list = list(x_string)                     
    x_reversedlist = reversed(x_list)          
    x_reversedstring = "".join(x_reversedlist)  
    x_reversed = int(x_reversedstring)          
    return x_reversed

def paliproduct(i1, i2):
    while i1 < 1000 and i2 < 1000:
            product = i1 * i2
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
            if product == reverseInteger(product):
                return product

print(paliproduct(100, 100))
```

I am using Python (which is obvious)... My question is why the shell did not try for all possible values of i1 to i2 (100-999) and broke after conducting one round for 100 and 100...

Comment: `return` will return _one_ value and then completely stop running that function. Ooh ahh!

Comment: because you have `return`.  so you basically exit the paliproduct method when you find the first match

Comment: As people have mentioned, it's the `return` that's breaking out of the `while` loop.

(As a side note, your `reverseInteger` function does not work as expected for integers ending in 0 because of the conversion back to an integer.)

Comment: As a side note. You can reverse an integer like this `int(str(x)[::-1])`

Answer (score 2):

It returns as soon as it finds a palindrome because you tell it to by using `return`:

```
if product == reverseInteger(product):
    return product
```

If you want to find all of the palindromes you need to modify how the `paliproduct` function works:

```
def paliproduct(i1, i2):
    palindromes = []
    while i1 < 1000 and i2 < 1000:
            product = i1 * i2
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
            if product == reverseInteger(product):
                palindromes.append(product)
    return palindromes
```

---

What I've done is created a `palindromes` list. Every time a `product` is a palindrome, I append it to the list (this is where your `return` statement was). At the end of the loop, I return the list.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you mean... Thanks a lot!

Comment: But when I ran the code it did not give me the correct answer... it should have given a list with **906609** being the largest, but instead it gave a lisst ([10201, 12321, 14641, 40804, 44944, 69696, 94249, 698896] where **698896** was the largest

Comment: @GlennMcGrath this happens because your `paliproduct` function goes only through exact squares, while `906609` is not an exact square

Comment: wait so could you suggest a way to improve my code such that it doesn't go through **JUST** exact squares

Comment: That is another question that you will need to post separately from this one

Comment: @GlennMcGrath you can do [this](https://ideone.com/gsWQXu) (note, that there is also an one-line solution in the file). If you need explanations regarding the code or how to fix original one you should really post a new question